# Central limit theorem application to general functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_n$ be a $\mathbb{N}$-valued random value. Suppose we have that
\begin{equation}
\frac{X_n-g(n)}{\sqrt{g(n)}}\sim N(0,1)
\end{equation}
for a function $g(n)$. This looks a lot like the Central Limit theorem - does this imply that $X_n\sim N(g(n),g(n))$ approximately? Or do we require that $X_n$ be replaced by the mean of $X_n$ for this? If so, what can we deduce about $X_n$ from this?

Comment: What does $\sim$ mean here?  Is $f(n)$ a random variable?

Comment: @Henry sorry, yes $f$ is a random variable

Comment: Does $\sim$ mean that the distribution of $\frac{f(n)-g(n)}{\sqrt{g(n)}}$ *is* the distribution of $N(0,1)$ or that it *converges towards* the distribution of $N(0,1)$ as $n$ increases? If the latter, the answer is "yes-ish for large enough $n$" but you have no detailed information about how big "large enough" might be.  The "ish" includes $f(n)$ may not have a mean for any $n$ (convergence in distribution is a very weak property)

Comment: Do you suppose that $g(n)$ is a random variable?